# How do I place two DataGrids on a desktop screen with .NET Maui

Tags: c#, maui, desktop-application, syncfusion

I wrote a program in WinForms C# and it works with no problem. On Windows. That is the problem. it only works on Windows. So I'm trying to switch it over to .NET Maui where I can compile it into both Windows and MacOS. The problem I'm having with .NET Maui is, my application is desktop and I want to place two Syncfusion DataGrids on the front screen.

I though adding a second Content Page would solve the problem. So I created a second Content Page and placed the DataGrid in itml.cs as Syncfusion said. But all that did was create separate xaml and xaml.cs files. So I'm still stuck on how do I place two DataGrids on the same desktop screen?

Comment: Use a [layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/)

Answer (score 1):

To place two Syncfusion DataGrids on the same desktop screen in a .NET Maui application, you can follow these steps:

- Create a new .NET Maui project if you haven't already.
- In your    project, open the XAML file of your main page (e.g.,
  MainPage.xaml).
- Inside the main  tag, add a layout container that supports multiple children, such as a  or .
- Within the layout container, add two separate Syncfusion:SfDataGrid
  elements, each representing one of the DataGrids you want to display.
- Configure the DataGrids by setting their properties, defining
  columns, and binding data as necessary.
- You can do this in XAML or in    the code-behind file (e.g.,
  MainPage.xaml.cs) using the provided
- APIs. Build and run your .NET Maui application.

Comment: I did what you said only I could not add BindingContext for the second DataGrid because I already have it set for the first one. The thing is I think I need it set to something different. So How can I get around this?

Comment: The DataGrid should have the BindingContext property and you can set the different binding context to the different DataGrids. @BobG